# Building Error on the IOS distribution using ionic in Windows

Tags: ios, windows, cordova, ionic-framework, ipa

I am very new in ionic iOS building. I got struck while not able to build the ios production .ipa file in ionic.io.
By referring the [site](http://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-create-an-ios-provisioning-profile-and-p12-with-windows/)

My Working Platforms:

1. Windows 8.1,
2. ionic.io,
3. Commands using CLI for running the app in browser and building.

**For IOS Development,**

1. I can able to create the p12 and mobile provisioning certificates in apple developer portal.
2. I can able to upload those files in the settings tab in the profile tag in ionic.io
3. I got my success build .ipa and ran into my iOS devices that working fine.

**For IOS Production,**

1. I can able to create the p12 and mobile provisioning certificates in apple developer portal.
2. I can able to upload those files in the settings tab in the profile tag in ionic.io
3. The build was failed in ionic.io. When i click the output link displaying the following error,

   ```
   === BUILD TARGET XXXX OF PROJECT XXXX WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
   Check dependencies Code Sign error: No code signing identities found:
   No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) were found.

   ** BUILD FAILED **
   ```

Can anyone help to resolve it

Comment: Usualky you'll set your singing identity using xCode, which is not available for windows

Comment: you can try third party building service like https://build.phonegap.com/ or http://ionic.io/cloud#packaging

Comment: Hey thanks guys, I am using ionic for building the ios app https://apps.ionic.io. If i get solution using ionic will be more helpfull. I am purely windows guys, i found lot of solutions related Xcode